# showing a null value in NSdateformatter

Tags: objective-c, ios7

From the the log start time value is printed. why end time showing (null) value.

```
NSString *start=@"00:01:00";
NSString *end=@"24:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *end1=[[NSDate alloc]init];
end1=[formatter1 dateFromString:end];
NSLog(@"end1:%@",end1);

**Log print - end1:(null)**NSDate *start1=[[NSDate alloc]init];start1=[formatter1 dateFromString:start];NSLog(@"start1:%@",start1);**Log print - start1:1999-12-31 18:31:00 +0000**
```

Comment: Format your question.. so that it could be easily read..

Comment: `@"24:00:00"` is a wrong format for NSDate representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hour value must be within 0 and 23, so 24 is an invalid hour value even for a 24hour date formatter. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns for valid values and formatters.

Since 24 as hour is invalid, the formatter returns `nil` . In your case you would need to add the date to achieve start 00:01:00 and end 00:00:00 which is the beginning of the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSString *end = @"00:00:00";
```

instead of

```
NSString *end = @"24:00:00";
```